# payment method in online shopping using xampp phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, phpmyadmin

I have this final project for Web Development that relates to online shopping.

Here is my thoughts, i would like a customer to add (sample)credit card with information just like in a real credit card that has balance and etc etc, i wanted to know how to make transactions where the admin gets the payments from the  customers that they used to purchase a product using (sample)credit card to the admins bank balance.

i dont really like to prefer paypal or any link transactions that would need an internet connection since this is just a FINAL project.i just need it to be offline where i could access all information in database.

if possible , i would like to hear suggestions from anyone :)

PS. please dont correct me if i have mistakes on my ideas, im still a student who wants to learn more from someone who is willing to teach me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

Create a sample database which holds a card information so that you can see the balance being updated for the consumer and the merchant.

Create a 'pay' page where the user views there final shopping list with all items purchased. Once a payment has been made it will show the update on the consumer and merchant's balance.

You can also have a transaction page to see all purchased made.

Comment: thanks .. im still trying to make codes for that thing .. its hard to rely on paypal where you need to deposit real money in order you could use the payment system ..